# Unity Lean touch cannot move object displayed on top of Image UI-> Image

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have displayed a 3d object on top of Ui Image, and applied lean touch library on 3d object for moving, scaling and rotating the object. The issue is I am able to scale and rotate the object but cannot move it. I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment yet, so I need to put there as an answer.
In one of my projects, I was using a [TouchKit](https://github.com/prime31/TouchKit) Unity3D tool. It has many features like rotating and moving objects.

Answer (score 0):

to move your 3d object, you need to use LeanTranslate script and add it to your 3d object.